# (STOREDPROC) Generated SELECT statement: looking for the right syntax to use near NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, tableadapter

I am using stored procedure in creating table adapter. This is my syntax:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `lcs_rdb`.`sp_EmployeeListReport`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_EmployeeListReport`(in where_clause TEXT)
BEGIN
        SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT        
                emp.employee_id, 
                group_concat(distinct `ext`.`extension_number` separator ',') AS extension_number,
                emp.employee_lastname, emp.employee_firstname, 
                dept.department_description, 
                divs.division_description, 
                grps.group_description, 
                st.site_name, emp.audit_date,
                group_concat(distinct `cst_ctr`.`cost_center_description` separator ',') AS cost_center_description
                FROM employees emp INNER JOIN
                 employee_extensions emp_ext ON emp_ext.employee_id = emp.employee_id INNER JOIN
                 extensions ext ON ext.extension_id = emp_ext.extension_id INNER JOIN
                 departments dept ON emp.department_id = dept.department_id INNER JOIN
                 divisions divs ON dept.division_id = divs.division_id INNER JOIN
                 groups grps ON divs.group_id = grps.group_id INNER JOIN
                 sites st ON emp.site_id = st.site_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 employee_cost_centers emp_cstctr ON emp.employee_id = emp_cstctr.employee_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 cost_centers cst_ctr ON emp_cstctr.cost_center_id = cst_ctr.cost_center_id
                where ", where_clause ,"");
 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
 EXECUTE stmt;
 DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
   END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This is the error when I executed it:
*"Generated SELECT statement.
   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1"*

I think, the problem is in the where clause. But I don't know how to fix it. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CONCAT()` returns `NULL` if any values are `NULL`.  Perhaps you want something like:

```
CONCAT('select . . .',
       COALESCE(where_clause, '1 = 1'))
```

Comment: Oh, wait. Look at my code behind. :( it says: **Argument not specified for parameter 'where_clause' of 'Public Overridable Overloads Function Fill(dataTable As LCSRDBDataSet.CostCenterStandardDataTable, where_clause As String) As Integer'. ** The syntax is: *daCostCenterStandard.Fill(dtCostCenterStandard)*

Comment: Be that as it may, *the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1* error from a prepared statement means that `@sql` **is indeed null** because at least one of the arguments is (unexpectedly) null.  The solution will involve figuring out which one(s).